# How do I specifically ignore a collapsed menu's expansion so certain items don't move with it?

Tags: html, css

On my website I have two expandable menus, one of which is a navbar, another a playlist. I'd like to make it so all of the items on the website move down when the navbar is expanded (which I did), but also make it so no items react when the playlist is opened. In my case, a cat photo and the pageselector are forced to move down when the "Zelda Playlist" is expanded. How can I fix this so that they ignore it?

Note: The page is really scuffed because all of my other elements are missing but you can still see the problem if you expand the snippet.

```css
.collapsibleWrapper {
  position: relative;
  right: 3%;
  bottom: 1px;
  max-width: 28%;
  margin-left: auto;
}

.collapsibleWrapper .btn-primary {
  max-width: 80px;
  float: right;
  margin-left: 100%;
}

.collapse,
.collapsing {
  width: 100% !important;
}

#footer {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2.5rem;
}

#pgselect {
  position: absolute;
  width: 133.859375px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

#catbanner {
  position: relative;
  left: 30px;
  bottom: 0px;
  border: ;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Faster One">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="functions.js"></script>
  <title>My Webpage</title>
</head>

<body style="background-color:#EBEDF3; height:auto;">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-light" style="background-color: #e3f2fd;">
    <span class="navbar-brand mb-0 h1">ABC</span>
    <h2 style="font-size:26px;">Contact us at: abcdefgh@gmail.com | ###-####-####</h2>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
      <ul id="navbaritems" class="navbar-nav">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-info disabled">Home</a>
     </ul>
   </nav>
    <div class="collapsibleWrapper">
      <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseExample" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
                Zelda Playlist
            </button>
        <div class="collapse" id="collapseExample" style="width:28%;">
          <div class="card card-body">
            <div class="accordion" id="accordionExample">
              <div class="card" style="width:99%;">
                <div class="card-header" id="headingOne" style="text-align:center">
                  <h2 class="mb-0">
                    <button class="btn btn-secondary text-center collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseOne">
                                        Dragon Roost Island - Wind Waker
                                    </button>
                  </h2>
                </div>
                <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-parent="#accordionExample">
                  <div class="card-body" style="text-align:center">
                    <audio controls>
                                        <source src="dragonroost.mp3">
                                    </audio>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="card" style="width:99%;">
                <div class="card-header" id="headingTwo" style="text-align:center">
                  <h2 class="mb-0">
                    <button class="btn btn-secondary text-center collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
                                        Gerudo Valley - Ocarina of Time
                                    </button>
                  </h2>
                </div>
                <div id="collapseTwo" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingTwo" data-parent="#accordionExample">
                  <div class="card-body" style="text-align:center">
                    <audio controls>
                                        <source src="gerudo.mp3">
                                    </audio>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="card" style="width:99%;">
                <div class="card-header" id="headingThree" style="text-align:center">
                  <h2 class="mb-0">
                    <button class="btn btn-secondary text-center collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseThree" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree">
                                        Lost Woods - Ocarina of Time
                                    </button>
                  </h2>
                </div>
                <div id="collapseThree" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingThree" data-parent="#accordionExample">
                  <div class="card-body" style="text-align:center">
                    <audio controls>
                                        <source src="lostwoods.mp3">
                                    </audio>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="catbanner" class="card card-body">
      <img src="catbanner.jpg" alt="Four Cats">
    </div>
    <footer id="footer">
      <div id="pgselect" class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Button group with nested dropdown">
        <div class="btn-group" role="group">
          <button id="dropdownMenuButton" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                        Page 1
                    </button>
          <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="btnGroupDrop1">
            <a class="dropdown-item disabled">1</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="page2.html">2</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="page3.html">3</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="page4.html">4</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <button onclick="window.location.href='page2.html';" type="btn" class="btn btn-secondary">-></button>
      </div>
    </footer>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-wHAiFfRlMFy6i5SRaxvfOCifBUQy1xHdJ/yoi7FRNXMRBu5WHdZYu1hA6ZOblgut" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B0UglyR+jN6CkvvICOB2joaf5I4l3gm9GU6Hc1og6Ls7i6U/mkkaduKaBhlAXv9k" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="functions.js"></script>
    <audio src="coin.wav" autostart="false" width="0" height="0" id="coin" enablejavascript="true">
        <audio src="death.wav" autostart="false" width="0" height="0" id="death" enablejavascript="true">
            <script>
                var death = document.getElementById("death");
                death.volume = 0.2;
            </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prevent things from being bumped down you will need to pull the dropdown playlist out of the document flow, with `position:absolute`

```
#collapseExample {
    position: absolute;
    top: 62px;
}
```

The top property is to position the dropdown below the button, the value can be different depending on your design preferences. See it in action below;

```css
.collapsibleWrapper {
  position: relative;
  right: 3%;
  bottom: 1px;
  max-width: 28%;
  margin-left: auto;
}

.collapsibleWrapper .btn-primary {
  max-width: 80px;
  float: right;
  margin-left: 100%;
}

.collapse,
.collapsing {
  width: 100% !important;
}

#collapseExample {
    position: absolute;
    top: 62px;
}
#footer {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2.5rem;
}

#pgselect {
  position: absolute;
  width: 133.859375px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

#catbanner {
  position: relative;
  left: 30px;
  bottom: 0px;
  border: ;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Faster One">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="functions.js"></script>
  <title>My Webpage</title>
</head>

<body style="background-color:#EBEDF3; height:auto;">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-light" style="background-color: #e3f2fd;">
    <span class="navbar-brand mb-0 h1">ABC</span>
    <h2 style="font-size:26px;">Contact us at: abcdefgh@gmail.com | ###-####-####</h2>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
      <ul id="navbaritems" class="navbar-nav">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-info disabled">Home</a>
     </ul>
   </nav>
    <div class="collapsibleWrapper">
      <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseExample" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
                Zelda Playlist
            </button>
        <div class="collapse" id="collapseExample" style="width:28%;">
          <div class="card card-body">
            <div class="accordion" id="accordionExample">
              <div class="card" style="width:99%;">
                <div class="card-header" id="headingOne" style="text-align:center">
                  <h2 class="mb-0">
                    <button class="btn btn-secondary text-center collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseOne">
                                        Dragon Roost Island - Wind Waker
                                    </button>
                  </h2>
                </div>
                <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-parent="#accordionExample">
                  <div class="card-body" style="text-align:center">
                    <audio controls>
                                        <source src="dragonroost.mp3">
                                    </audio>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="card" style="width:99%;">
                <div class="card-header" id="headingTwo" style="text-align:center">
                  <h2 class="mb-0">
                    <button class="btn btn-secondary text-center collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
                                        Gerudo Valley - Ocarina of Time
                                    </button>
                  </h2>
                </div>
                <div id="collapseTwo" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingTwo" data-parent="#accordionExample">
                  <div class="card-body" style="text-align:center">
                    <audio controls>
                                        <source src="gerudo.mp3">
                                    </audio>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="card" style="width:99%;">
                <div class="card-header" id="headingThree" style="text-align:center">
                  <h2 class="mb-0">
                    <button class="btn btn-secondary text-center collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseThree" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree">
                                        Lost Woods - Ocarina of Time
                                    </button>
                  </h2>
                </div>
                <div id="collapseThree" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingThree" data-parent="#accordionExample">
                  <div class="card-body" style="text-align:center">
                    <audio controls>
                                        <source src="lostwoods.mp3">
                                    </audio>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="catbanner" class="card card-body">
      <img src="catbanner.jpg" alt="Four Cats">
    </div>
    <footer id="footer">
      <div id="pgselect" class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Button group with nested dropdown">
        <div class="btn-group" role="group">
          <button id="dropdownMenuButton" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                        Page 1
                    </button>
          <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="btnGroupDrop1">
            <a class="dropdown-item disabled">1</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="page2.html">2</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="page3.html">3</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="page4.html">4</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <button onclick="window.location.href='page2.html';" type="btn" class="btn btn-secondary">-></button>
      </div>
    </footer>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-wHAiFfRlMFy6i5SRaxvfOCifBUQy1xHdJ/yoi7FRNXMRBu5WHdZYu1hA6ZOblgut" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B0UglyR+jN6CkvvICOB2joaf5I4l3gm9GU6Hc1og6Ls7i6U/mkkaduKaBhlAXv9k" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="functions.js"></script>
    <audio src="coin.wav" autostart="false" width="0" height="0" id="coin" enablejavascript="true">
        <audio src="death.wav" autostart="false" width="0" height="0" id="death" enablejavascript="true">
            <script>
                var death = document.getElementById("death");
                death.volume = 0.2;
            </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: or you can try doing position:fixed also

Comment: I know about absolute but the problem is that I also have a navbar that expands and by setting the position to fixed or absolute, it makes it so the playlist doesnt do down when the navbar is expanded. So basically, I'd like to leave the playlist so it moves down with the navbar, but also make it so when the playlist is expanded, nothing below it is affected.

Comment: @meematzzz is this 'navbar' the page selector you've got wrapped in a footer, or is it something you've not included in the snippet?

Comment: @Jasmine The page selector is the gray rectangle at the bottom with an arrow on the right and "Page 1" in the middle. Navbar isnt included in the snippet but it also has a collapse menu that pushes everything down which was my goal. The problem is that the collapse menu in "Zelda Playlist" pushes down the cat image and page selector, which I don't want. I dont want the collapsed menu in the playlist to push anything down

Comment: @meematzzz since the navbar seems to be an important factor you should include an approximation of it in your code snippet, so we can see how it interacts and how our solutions might affect it. As I don't see how my solution could be a problem as it only applies to the playlist dropdown container and not the button itself.

Comment: @Jasmine I created a mini model of my navbar. You should be able to see my problem now.

When the navbar is expanded, everything moves down (thats what I want), but when the playlist is expanded, things below it move down (which I dont want). I'd like it so the playlist still moves down, but doesn't move anything else down.

Comment: @meematzzz please see my answer again with the snippet so you can see it working. navbar is still pushing things down, incl. playlist, but the playlist doesn't push anything down....